# Get browser opened tabs title in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, frontend

I would like to know if it is possible in javascript to do something like this:

I'm on my website named mysite. I open three tabs "1 2 3" from mysite. I'm actually one tab 2, then I'd like to change the title of tabs 1 and 3.
Then, if i go tab 3, I'd like to change tab 1 and 2 title.

Is something like that possible ? I'm looking for a solution in vain. I thought maybe set sessionStorage information at the opening of a new tab...

If anyone can help me, he'll have all my gratitude !

By comunity !

Comment: You will have to use localStorage. SessionStorage is not shared across tab, I guess. You will have to also set unique IDs to tabs and based on `window.focus` event, you can do your logic.

Comment: You need to utilize [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) and the [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the onblur and onfocus events for the window object.
So something like this (this is native javascript, no jquery).

```
window.onblur = function () { document.title = 'you went?'; }
window.onfocus = function () { document.title = 'you came back'; }
```